# Ehcache: java type cannot be cast to entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I have project where I use spring caching with Ehcache technology. Also I use hibernate as jpa provider.
My request method invoke create several thread for data processing.

It works well when I use different caches for every method of my service module in ehcache.xml like this:

```
<cache name="rrr1"
   maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
   maxEntriesLocalDisk="100000000"
   eternal="false"
   diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
   timeToIdleSeconds="300"
   timeToLiveSeconds="600"
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
   overflowToDisk="false"
   diskPersistent="false"
   transactionalMode="off">
</cache>

<cache name="rrr2"
   maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
   maxEntriesLocalDisk="100000000"
   eternal="false"
   diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
   timeToIdleSeconds="300"
   timeToLiveSeconds="600"
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
   overflowToDisk="false"
   diskPersistent="false"
   transactionalMode="off">
</cache>

<cache name="rrr3"
   maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
   maxEntriesLocalDisk="100000000"
   eternal="false"
   diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
   timeToIdleSeconds="300"
   timeToLiveSeconds="600"
   memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
   overflowToDisk="false"
   diskPersistent="false"
   transactionalMode="off">
</cache>
```

But when I try to set single cache for my methods, I get issue like this:

```
2016-08-05 11:12:11.385  INFO 46536 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.0.Final}
2016-08-05 11:12:11.387  INFO 46536 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-05 11:12:11.388  INFO 46536 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-05 11:12:11.426  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-08-05 11:12:11.723  INFO 46536 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
2016-08-05 11:12:12.110  WARN 46536 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl        : Unrecognized hbm2ddl_auto value : none.  Supported values include create, create-drop, update, and validate.  Ignoring
2016-08-05 11:12:12.667  INFO 46536 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-05 11:12:12.910  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.s.c.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean  : Initializing EhCache CacheManager
2016-08-05 11:12:12.941  WARN 46536 --- [           main] n.sf.ehcache.config.CacheConfiguration   : Statistics can no longer be enabled via configuration.
2016-08-05 11:12:13.560  INFO 46536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@78691363: startup date [Fri Aug 05 11:12:08 NOVT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-05 11:12:13.664  INFO 46536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting]}" onto public com.example.Greeting com.example.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String)
2016-08-05 11:12:13.666  INFO 46536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-05 11:12:13.667  INFO 46536 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-05 11:12:13.715  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-05 11:12:13.715  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-05 11:12:13.772  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-05 11:12:14.379  INFO 46536 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-05 11:12:14.457  INFO 46536 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-05 11:12:14.462  INFO 46536 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 6.507 seconds (JVM running for 7.062)
2016-08-05 11:12:32.666  INFO 46536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-05 11:12:32.666  INFO 46536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-05 11:12:32.685  INFO 46536 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 19 ms
2016-08-05 11:12:33.162  INFO 46536 --- [       Thread-6] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.Standart
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.model.bs.Org
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.model.bs.Org
ChrgServ: Error in thread:: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.ric.bill.model.bs.Org
```

Where com.ric.bill.Standart and com.ric.bill.model.bs.Org - my Entities

Why does it happen?

My ehcache.xml (not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="false">
    <diskStore path="cacheIO" />

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="1000000" eternal="true"
                  overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
                  timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
                  diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="1800" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="FIFO">
    </defaultCache>

    <cache name="org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache"
        maxElementsInMemory="1000000" eternal="true" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        overflowToDisk="false" />
    <cache

    name="org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"
    maxEntriesLocalHeap="5000"
    eternal="true"/>

    <cache name="rrr1" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000000" 
        eternal="true" 
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="100"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
        overflowToDisk="false"
        transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>

    <cache name="rrr2" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000000" 
        eternal="true" 
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="100"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>

    <cache name="rrr3" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="1000000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000000" 
        eternal="true" 
        diskPersistent="false"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="100"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
        overflowToDisk="false" 
        transactionalMode="off">
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

My methods:

```
package com.ric.bill.mm.impl;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.ric.bill.Calc;
import com.ric.bill.Storable;
import com.ric.bill.Utl;
import com.ric.bill.dao.ParDAO;
import com.ric.bill.excp.WrongGetMethod;
import com.ric.bill.mm.ParMng;
import com.ric.bill.model.bs.Dw;
import com.ric.bill.model.bs.Par;

@Service
public class ParMngImpl implements ParMng {

    @Autowired
    private ParDAO pDao;

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="rrr1", key="{ #cd }")
    public synchronized boolean isExByCd(String cd) {
        Par p = getByCD(cd);
        if (p != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="rrr1", key="{ #st.getKlsk(), #cd, #genDt }")
    public synchronized Double getDbl(Storable st, String cd, Date genDt) {
        Par par = getByCD(cd);
        try {
            for (Dw d: st.getDw()) {
                //по соотв.периоду
                if (Utl.between(genDt, d.getDt1(), d.getDt2())) {
                    //проверка, что соответствует CD и Number (NM), Единичное (SI) - убрал - тормозит
                    /*if (checkPar(d.getFkHfp(), cd, "SI")) {
                        return d.getN1();
                    }*/
                    //if (d.getPar().getCd().equals(cd)) {
                    if (d.getPar().equals(par)) {
                        if (d.getPar().getTp().equals("NM")) {
                            if (d.getPar().getDataTp().equals("SI")) {
                                return d.getN1();
                            } else {
                                    throw new WrongGetMethod("Попытка получить параметр "+cd+" не являющийся типом данного SI завершилась ошибкой");
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new WrongGetMethod("Попытка получить параметр "+cd+" не являющийся типом NM завершилась ошибкой");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //если не найдено, то проверить, существует ли вообще этот параметр, в базе данных
            if (!isExByCd(cd)) {
                throw new WrongGetMethod("Параметр "+cd+" не существует в базе данных");
            };
        } catch (WrongGetMethod e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames="rrr1", key="{ #st.getKlsk(), #cd }")
    public synchronized Double getDbl(Storable st, String cd) {
        Par par = getByCD(cd);
        try {
            for (Dw d: st.getDw()) {
                if (d.getPar().equals(par)) {
                    if (d.getPar().getTp().equals("NM")) {
                        if (d.getPar().getDataTp().equals("SI")) {
                            return d.getN1();
                        } else {
                                throw new WrongGetMethod("Попытка получить параметр "+cd+" не являющийся типом данного SI завершилась ошибкой");
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw new WrongGetMethod("Попытка получить параметр "+cd+" не являющийся типом NM завершилась ошибкой");
                    }
                }
            }
            //если не найдено, то проверить, существует ли вообще этот параметр, в базе данных
            if (!isExByCd(cd)) {
                throw new WrongGetMethod("Параметр "+cd+" не существует в базе данных");
            };
        } catch (WrongGetMethod e) {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
          <artifactId>Billing</artifactId>
          <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
          <exclusion> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion> 
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc14 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
            <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency> 


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.1-GA</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```